# I can't set the custom conversion event to be active in Meta Pixel. what did i do wrong?

Tags: facebook, ads, facebook-ads-api

[image: custom conversion]

so, i want to set the custom conversion to active whenever the URL i have added is accessed. but it doesn't seem to be active. basically i want to differentiate which product is generating initiate_checkout event. any solutions?

tried deleting and setting it up again. but the problem persists